# Get first element image in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I want get image from image table and I have this error

```
Attempt to read property "image" on null
```

this is my code in blade

```
{{ $product->image->first()->image }}
```

when I print without 'image' it returns this

```
{{ $product->image->first() }}
```

```
{"id":1,"product_id":2,"image":"public\/images\/product\/Dsb41wUTpFCEmiEjTVnuAsPqhbZrLaQHIfFIAhVe.jpg","created_at":"2023-05-01T16:05:07.000000Z","updated_at":"2023-05-01T16:05:07.000000Z"}
```

Can you tell me what the problem is?

Comment: `->first()` can return `null`, and `null->image` is not valid... Try `{{ optional($product->image->first())->image }}`, or `{{ $product->image->first()?->image }}`

Answer (score 1):

The relation `$product->image` can return `null`, and `null->image` is your error.
You can try on blade these options:

- [optional()](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/helpers#method-optional) method:

`{{ optional($product->image)->image }}`

- [php ?](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php#migration71.new-features.nullable-types):

`{{ $product->image->first()?->image }}`

- [php ??](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op):

`{{ $product->image->first()->image ?? 'Image not Found' }}`